# How do I dual boot with 2 linux distros of the same name?

Tags: linux, installation, multi-boot, grub

I'm trying to install Artix linux on UEFI, however i already have an Artix system installed on my desktop, which i'm trying to dual boot a second installation of Artix with (because the first one just.. can't install other DE's, and i broke kwin).

I'm wondering: How does `grub` handle the fact that there are 2 distros with the same name?
Do i have to format the ESP and use `os-prober` to search the first one, or  do I have to keep it as is and reinstall/update grub?

Also when I try to mount the swap partition, I get the following error message:

```
# swapon /dev/disk/by-label/swap
swapon: /dev/sda3: swapon failed: Device or resource busy
```

Comment: Theoretically, if they're on different partitions, there should be no conflict. However, you may have only a single swap partition for the two OS's -- either create a separate swap partition for each, or. if you can do as some distros allow, switch to a swap **file** on the same partition as the OS.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik what about The Efi system partition? do i have to format it or leave it as it is?

Comment: @floenele - If you format your EFI partition, you will be unable to boot into any operating system, don't format your EFI partition